# Limitation of AddSoftware directive in INF

Tags: uwp, driver

I am testing INF AddSoftware function in my driver.
My driver can download UWP APP on Windows Store by SoftwareID after driver is installed.

```
SoftwareType=2
SoftwareID=pfn://Publiser.xxxxxxx_xxxxxx
```

However if I uninstall the downloaded UWP APP manually, the APP will not be installed again even if I do following update:

1. Reinstall driver (Uninstall Device & install inf)
2. Update driver version
3. Update APP version on Store

Is this normal behavior that the APP will not install again after user uninstalls it?
Or is there any related information about this limitation? [MSDN does not mention about this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-addsoftware-directive#software-install-section-softwareid)

Thank you all in advance.